# Path finding algorithm excercise and working with .txt files

Tags: python, path-finding

This is a homework which was given to me and I have been struggling with writing the solution.

Write a program that finds the longest adjacent sequence of colors in a matrix(2D grid). Colors are represented by ‘R’, ‘G’, ‘B’ characters (respectively Red, Green and Blue).
You will be provided with 4 individual test cases, which must also be included in your solution.
An example of your solution root directory should look like this:

> solutionRootDir
> | - (my solution files and folders)
> | - tests/
> | - test_1
> | - test_2
> | - test_3
> | - test_4

1. Individual test case input format:

- First you should read two whitespace separated 32-bit integers from the provided test case
- that represents the size (rows and cols) of the matrix.
- Next you should read rows number of newline separated lines of 8-bit characters.
  Your program should find and print the longest adjacent sequence (diagonals are not counted as adjacent fields),
  and print to the standard output the number.
  NOTE: in case of several sequences with the same length – simply print their equal length.

> test_1
> Provided input:
> 3 3
> R R B
> G G R
> R B G
> Expected Output:
> 2

> test_2
> Provided input:
> 4 4
> R R R G
> G B R G
> R G G G
> G G B B
> Expected Output:
> 7

> test_3
> Provided input:
> 6 6
> R R B B B B
> B R B B G B
> B G G B R B
> B B R B G B
> R B R B R B
> R B B B G B
> Expected Output:
> 22

> test_4
> Provided input:
> 1000 1000
> 1000 rows of 1000 R’s
> Expected Output:
> 1000000

2. Your program entry point should accepted from one to four additional parameters.
   Those parameters will indicate the names of the test cases that your program should run.

• Example 1: ./myprogram test_1 test_3

• Example 2: ./myprogram test_1 test_2 test_3 test_4

• you can assume that the input from the user will be correct (no validation is required)

```py
import numpy as np

a = int(input("Enter rows: "))
b = int(input("Enter columns: "))
rgb = ["R", "G", "B"]
T = [[0 for col in range(b)] for row in range(a)]

for row in range(a):
    for col in range(b):
        T[row][col] = np.random.choice(rgb)

for r in T:
    for c in r:
        print(c, end=" ")
    print()

def solution(t):
    rows: int = len(t)
    cols: int = len(t[0])
    longest = np.empty((rows, cols))
    longest_sean = 1

    for i in range(rows - 1, -1, -1):
        for j in range(cols - 1, -1, -1):
            target = t[i][j]

            current = 1

            for ii in range(i, rows):
                for jj in range(j, cols):
                    length = 1
                    if target == t[ii][jj]:
                        length += longest[ii][jj]
                    current = max(current, length)

            longest[i][j] = current
            longest_sean = max(current, longest_sean)

    return longest_sean

print(solution(T))
```

Comment: Please post the code you've tried so far - see [ask] and [mre].

Comment: I have no idea how to work with files. So far, I have read several articles and non of them helped me, so I focused on the algorithm and that is how far I have come.

Comment: Well, that looks like a start ... now what is the exact problem?

Comment: There are three problems...the first one is that I can't seem to understand how to make the solution accept at least one or  a maximum of four parameters from the console and based on that execute the solution on all of the test cases entered from the console which are situated in the solution directory in the form of .txt files. The second one is how to make the solution analyse the test case and accept the two integers as matrix(2D array) values for rows and columns and the letters to be loaded in that matrix(2D array). The third issue is that the algorithm doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to get the parameters from the console execution you have to use sys.argv so `from sys import argv`. than convert your text field to python lists like this

```py
def load(file):
    with open(file+".txt") as f:
        data = f.readlines()
    res = []
    for row in data:
        res.append([])
        for element in row:
            if element != "\n" and element != " ":
                res[-1].append(element)

    return res
```

witch will create a 2 dimentional list of containing `"R"`, `"B"` and `"G"`. than you can simply look for the longest area of one Value like using this Function:

```
def findLargest(data):
    visited = []
    area = []
    length = 0
    movement = [(1,0), (0,1), (-1,0),(0,-1)]

    def recScan(x, y, scanArea):
        visited.append((x,y))
        scanArea.append((x,y))
        
        for dx, dy in movement:
            newX, newY = x+dx, y+dy
            if newX >= 0 and newY >= 0 and newX < len(data) and newY < len(data[newX]):
                if data[x][y] == data[newX][newY] and (not (newX, newY) in visited):
                    recScan(newX, newY, scanArea)
        return scanArea
            

    for x in range(len(data)):
        for y in range(len(data[x])):
            if (x, y) not in visited:
                newArea = recScan(x, y, [])
                if len(newArea) > length:
                    length = len(newArea)
                    area = newArea
    return length, area
```

whereby `recScan` will check all adjacent fields that haven't bean visited jet. than just call the functions like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for file in argv[1:]:
        data = load(file)
        print(findLargest(data))
```

the argv[1:] is reqired because the first argument passed to python witch is the file you want to execute. my data structure is.

> main.py
> test_1.txt
> test_2.txt
> test_3.txt
> test_4.txt

and test_1 threw test_4 look like this just with other values.

---

R R B B B B
B R B B G B
B G G B R B
B B R B G B
R B R B R B
R B B B G B

---

Comment: Thank you so much for the answere! How do I specify which test files to load for execution from the console and why is there no output, I used the code you posted and made my directory the same way as yours?

Comment: to run the code you have to use the command ``python main.py a b ...`` where it will run it for a, b, etc so to run Example 1 the command is ``python main.py test_1 test_3`` and for example 2 the command is ``python main.py test_1 test_2 test_3 test_4`` and so forth.